# Record in db not being created, but code acting as if it were?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm testing my code. If certain fields are left blank (namely `pickupdate` & `returndate`), the record should NOT be created. This is very clearly stated in the model:

```
  validate :custom_validation

  def custom_validation
    errors[:base] << "Please enter both a pick up date and a return date" if self.pickupdate.blank? || self.returndate.blank?
    if self.pickupdate.present? && self.returndate.present?
      errors[:base] << "Please enter a pick up date and a return date on or after today" if (self.pickupdate.to_date < Date.today) || (self.returndate.to_date < Date.today)
      errors[:base] << "Please enter a return date that is on or after the pick up date" if self.pickupdate > self.returndate
      errors[:base] << "Please submit requests with a maximum 2-week duration, we don't have enough lenders at this time to offer long term borrows" if (self.returndate.to_date - self.pickupdate.to_date).to_i > 14
    end
  end
```

Futhermore, the model specs that are testing this are passing!

However, I just wrote an integration test that got stuck, and when I'm troubleshooting in the console, I'm trying to create a record with a blank `pickupdate` and a blank `returndate`. Then I do an `inspect` in the console and guess what??

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
INSPECT
#<Request id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, items: nil, detail: "i should not be created\r\n", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, edit_id: nil, heard: nil, pickupdate: nil, returndate: nil, signup_id: 2>
END
```

It appears via the console output above that the record is indeed being committed to the db. Now here's another pickle. When I go into `rails c` and look at `Request.last`, I find the `Request` from yesterday, not today.

I just want to know how this is happening... because even if the inspection is faulty and the record is not being committed to the db (I mean... it doesn't even have an id for itself), the bottom line is that my test is failing because it's continuing as if the record was saved. And therefore at some point down the line I get a nomethoderror on that record.

For reference, controller code:

```
@requestrecord = @signup_parent.requests.build #separate from create, because I need to check on some stuff before saving
if @requestrecord = @signup_parent.requests.create(@requestparams)
...
```

So basically, the `create` action is somehow returning as true even when `@requestparams` are totally empty. Now I can fix this problem by writing a wrapping if statement that explicitly checks for `@requestrecord.id` since that is not present from console log output above. But now my curiosity is piqued and I'm trying to learn what's causing this problem. Is it the separate `build` statement? I thought about that... but then.. shouldn't that not matter once I actually call a `create`?

Comment: the record isn't being created - it has an ID of nil.

Comment: Do you know why the code is acting as though it were?

Comment: I don't see any evidence of that in your question.

Comment: The integration test isn't passing, i.e., it keeps running code after the `if @requestrecord = @signup_parent.requests.create(@requestparams)`

Comment: OK. Can you rewrite the question to actually mention the error you are getting, the backtrace, etc. with the complete test that is failing? At the moment, none of that is present.